# How to "undo" `bytes()` encoding for a string?

Tags: python-3.x, sockets

In making a socket chat, I want to do certain behaviour depending on the message string.

```py
"""
c is a client socket
RECV_SIZE is the receiving buffer size
"""
message = c.recv(RECV_SIZE)
if message == bytes("/quit", "utf8"):
    # logic specific to quitting
```

This is using `/quit` as an example string. But is there a way to decode the message so I can access it in plain text? If `message` is printed, it's a garbled mess, I'd like to print the actual message decoded. Essentially I want the reverse of `bytes()`, or "unbytes" if that makes sense. So instead I would do something like:

```py
message = unbytes(c.recv(RECV_SIZE), "utf8")
if message == "/quit":
    # logic specific to quitting
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for the [`decode()`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=bytes#bytes.decode) method for `bytes`.

```
message = c.recv(RECV_SIZE).decode('utf8')
```